# How can I use git credentials in a shell script on Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

So I have a plain shell script and I want to execute 2 git commands but don't have the credentials. How do I get the credentials into my environment? Do I have to set GIT_ASKPASS or something? I am not the admin so "install a plugin" isn't a great option.

The environment has the following available already:

```
BUILD_URL
UPDATE_VERSION
HOSTNAME
PASS            <--- This one looks like a possible but still no user id. 
POM_GROUPID
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE
BUILD_TAG
POM_DISPLAYNAME
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
WORKSPACE
JOB_URL
RUN_CHANGES_DISPLAY_URL
POM_ARTIFACTID
MAVEN_OPTS
JENKINS_SWARM_VERSION
NLSPATH
GIT_COMMIT
JENKINS_HOME
MAVEN_HOME
PATH
RUN_DISPLAY_URL
PWD
JAVA_HOME
HUDSON_URL
JAVA_VERSION
JOB_NAME
POM_VERSION
BUILD_VERSION
XFILESEARCHPATH
BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME
BUILD_ID
JENKINS_URL
JOB_BASE_NAME
GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT
POM_PACKAGING
HOME
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY
SHLVL
M2_HOME
GIT_BRANCH
EXECUTOR_NUMBER
JENKINS_SERVER_COOKIE
GIT_URL
NODE_LABELS
HUDSON_HOME
NODE_NAME
BUILD_NUMBER
JOB_DISPLAY_URL
HUDSON_COOKIE
```

Update: here is some new information. GIT_ASKPASS uses these? ...and I note that Jenkins is using GIT_ASKPASS to check out in the first place.

```
+ git help -a
+ grep credential-
  credential-cache          remote-ext
  credential-cache--daemon  remote-fd
  credential-gnome-keyring  remote-ftp
  credential-store          remote-ftps
```

Comment: can you use ssh keys?

Comment: No. I'm a Ubuntu guy but this is a very "Windows" shop. :-/ Last time I checked port 22 was closed globally.  Anyway, it's not remote.

Answer (score 1):

If your script has to have those credentials, then you can check the second option "[Job DSL plugin: Build Variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Handling-Credentials#user-content-build-variables)"

> All build variables are exposed to the Job DSL scripts as variables, see [User Power Moves](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#access-the-jenkins-environment-variables).
>   There are several ways to define credentials as build variables, e.g. the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) provides a "Inject passwords to the build as environment variables" setting to inject passwords either defined globally in "Configure System" or directly on a job.

```
// use the FLOWDOCK_TOKEN variable to configure the Flowdock publisher
job('example-4') {
    publishers {
        flowdock(FLOWDOCK_TOKEN) {
            unstable()
            success()
            aborted()
            failure()
            fixed()
            notBuilt()
        }
    }
}

// variables can also be using in configure blocks
job('example-5') {
    configure { project ->
        project / builders << 'org.foo.FooBuilder' {
            userName(FOO_USER)
            password(FOO_PASSWORD)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As noted above, I'm not the admin. I cannot install plugins.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid I don't know much about Jenkins, but you can store a git credential from a shell script using your git credential helper (assuming you have one configured), e.g.:

```
printf "protocol=https/nhost=your.git.host/nusername=your_user/npassword=Y0urP@55w0rd/n/n" | git credential approve # git credential takes its arguments on stdin - the final double newline is needed to signal end of input
```

Git commands should then use it, or if you need the credential itself you can retrieve it on stdout with:

```
printf "protocol=https/nhost=your.git.host/username=your_user/npassword=Y0urP/n/n" | git credential fill
```